# $F(x)$ is a formal power series. Find $G(x)$ if $F(G(x)) = x.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, generating-functions, formal-power-series

$F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$. Find $G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g_nx^{n}$ if $F(G(x)) = x$. Specifically find a formula for $g_n$

I am learning about formal power series, so please don't use $\sin x = F(x)$ which I think is true here, hence we can easily get $G(x)$ using this way.

I tried $F(G(x)) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{G(x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ and somehow getting the coefficient of x as 1 and all other cofficients of $x^j$ as $0$. I am unable to do so. If I need to provide the tedious computation which is not leading me anywhere, I am happy to do so.

Comment: This is the power series for $\sin $.

Comment: g(x) = inverse of sine function. I don't want to approach this like that. I mentioned that already in the question. That teaches me nothing about proofs of formal power series

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my fault for rashly typing a comment. I didn't read your full question, obviously.

Comment: What you have here is a [_series reversion_](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) problem. The Mathworld page just linked has some discussion, as does Wikipedia's page on the Lagrange inversion theorem. (Also, while you may not want to use the fact of $G(x)=\sin^{-1}(x)$, you can at least use it to check your work.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Differentiate to get $F'(G(x))G'(x) = 1$. Then differentiate again to get

$F''(G(x))G'(x)+F'(G(x))G''(x) = 0$

but note $F''(G(x)) = -F(G(x))$ (this secretly is true because $F$ is sine, but of course can be verified by differentiating the power series), so

$F'(G(x))G''(x) = -xG'(x)$ and multiplying both sides by $G'(x)$ gives

$G''(x) = -x(G'(x))^2$

which we can use to solve for the coefficients of $G(x)$.

Comment: How do you prove product rule, chain rule for formal series? It looks so similar like differentiation of functions.

Comment: it's well known that these rules hold. you can look up the proofs online if you wish but I don't think they're that exciting

Comment: I am not finding anything easy to understand. By just using coefficients or something, not convergence and all. Any resource you can provide

Comment: so "formal series" means we can ignore questions of convergence. they aren't technically polynomials. you can think of them as infinite sequences where $(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)$ corresponds to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$. so all you have to do is compare coefficients.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570542/formal-power-series-the-chain-rule-and-the-product-rule

Comment: Thanks that looks easy to understand. I will try to do for chain rule following that.

Answer (score 1):

Your $G(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1} g_n x^n$ should start from $n=1$ and not 0. Then e.g.
$$ x = (g_1 x+g_2 x^2 + g_3 x^3+ \cdots) - (g_1 x + g_2 x^2+ \cdots)^3/3! + (g_1 x +\cdots)^5/5!+ \cdots$$
comes with  a natural grading and
allows  you to read off $g_1=1$, $g_2=0$, $g_3=1/6$,...

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1926283), it is shown that
for a formal power series
$$
x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nx^n
$$
the inverse series is
$$
x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty b_nx^n
$$
where the $b_n$ can be computed inductively using the composition formula
$$
0=a_n+b_n+\left[x^n\right]\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}b_k\left(x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\dots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\right)^k
$$
This may be arduous, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The method for computing the coefficients of the inverse function is known as [Lagrange inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem). In this particular case, we are inverting the sine function, hence we are interested in the power series around $x=0$ of $G(x)=\arcsin(x)$, and we may exploit the fact that the Taylor series of
$$ G'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = (1-x^2)^{-1/2} $$
can be computed from the extended binomial theorem:
$$ G'(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{-1/2}{n}(-1)^n x^{2n}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{x^{2n}}{4^n} $$
and by termwise integration:
$$ G(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)4^n}.$$
The radius of convergence of such a power series is $1$, by Weierstrass M-test or the fact that the closest singularities to the origin of $G'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ lie at $x=\pm 1$.